# Extract string after a delimiter like "/ " OpenOffice Calc

Tags: worksheet-function, copy-paste, openoffice, openoffice-calc, string

I have a file that converts inputs for me into an SKU-number (**S**tock **K**eeping **U**nit).

The names and attributes I have are in one line and one cell like so:

`Temperature Displaying Smart Ring / Rose Gold – 6`

Luckily it is all separated by a delimiter (`/`).

I managed to get it to work so that everything BEFORE the delimiter `/` gets extracted by using
`=LEFT(TRIM(Products.D2);FIND("/";TRIM(Products.D2))-1)`

However, I struggle to get it to work to extract everything AFTER the `/`.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Just as comment, since the following works with LibreOffice but nor with OpenOffice. With LibreOffice, you could make use of the REGEX() function to extract the partial string: `=REGEX(Products.D2;"\/(.*)";"$1")`. The regular expression searches for a "`/`" and returns all following character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use OpenOffice, but as the syntax is closed to Excel's, you can try the following formula to extract everything after the `\`:

```
=RIGHT(Products.D2;LEN(Products.D2)-FIND("/";TRIM(Products.D2))-1)
```

OR

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(Products.D2;LEN(Products.D2)-FIND("/";TRIM(Products.D2))))
```

Comment: Im getting an `Err:508` sadly

Comment: @itsolidude I have changed `,` to `;` as your regional settings are different from mine. Try again.

Comment: Is there a way to make its it gets extracted after the FIRST `/` some cells have multiple slashes

Comment: @itsolidude Can you show an example of what you mentioned?

Comment: I got it to work, thank you!